# Can an American fly to Spain with a one way ticket?

Tags: usa, tickets, spain

I am going to Ibiza to work for the summer and am unsure if I can buy a one way ticket. I want to leave the trip open ended because I have never been to Europe and want to explore. I am obtaining a work visa through the company I will be working for.

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Can you clarify what your concern is?

Comment: I suspect she's concerned that Spain will want evidence of his return ticket or something, like many other countries require.

Comment: comment, because I dont have evidence, but ordinarily most countries dont need a return ticket or similar proof if you have a Visa to work there, unless its a specific short term work visa

Answer (score 0):

Last September I flew into Paris with a one-way ticket, and nobody said a thing. Later I re-entered France by bus from the UK, and wasn't asked anything, either.

Spain and France are both part of the [Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area), and as such *ought* to have the same rules, so you shouldn't have any problem.

But it's still possible you might be asked about your travel plans.  Although most likely, you won't need to provide proof of onward travel--people come and go out of the Schengen area by train and car all the time.

It's probably even less of a concern if you have a work visa, as they expect you to be living there.

If you're *really* concerned, you could buy a bus or train ticket out of the Schengen Area, and provide that as proof of onward travel.  But if it were me, I would wait until I arrive in Spain. If they give you a hard time, order a ticket (assuming you can do so from your smart phone or something).

In fact, I *will* be doing exactly the same thing when I fly one-way to Spain at the end of July.

Comment: But the OP does not seem to want to go to Spain using Schengen rules (she mentioned a “work” visa and might be staying longer than 90 days). Note that not all work visas are intended as long-term residence permits. Obviously, all this sounds plausible but it would be better to have actual information about Spanish rules in this area.